# free internet based defect/issue management for ASP.Net absed project

Tags: bug-tracking, dms

I am working on a ASP.Net project with a team of 3 members. Due to geographical reasons, I need to have a defect management system that should be

- free (the project is low cost)
- internet based
- should allow 5-10 people

I was wondering if someone could suggest me a good solution or may be redirect me to some useful links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.aceproject.com/

http://Bug-Track.com/

http://www.defectr.com/

http://samba.anu.edu.au/cgi-bin/jitterbug

Comment: Defectr is really good. I am assessing it. Looks like it fullfills all my requirements. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

Project2Manage is an online project management application that helps you stay up-to-date, on task and connected with your team.

http://www.project2manage.com/